# area under the curve between two troughs rather than integrating between the two points

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, integral

I have a list of X(x) and Y(signal) data using which I am calculating the troughs:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
troughs, _= find_peaks(-signal)
```

Now I want to calculate the integral between the first trough and the last trough

```
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline   
x = range(1,len(signal)+1)
f = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y)
f.integral(peaks[1], peaks[-1])
which gives me: -1.477
```

Given  that this value is negative is consistent with the fact that it is calculating the integral. But what about Area Under the Curve? We know that they are not equal to each other as integral could be negative yet AUC cannot. 
Is there any easy way to calculate AUC between two different points? One way I could think of is divide Y into negative and non negative groups and do the integral for each group separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `abs` value for the function.
Is the same of

> divide Y into negative and non negative groups and do the integral for
>   each group separately

but more fastly.

Mathematically it should work ... but i don't know if this is whath you want.

Hope it's helpful. :)